# How to check if a Character is a word boundary

Tags: swift, unicode, swift3

How do I check if a `Character` is a word boundary (as defined on [Unicode  TR#29](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29))?

I have a solution using a regex but I thinks it's ugly.

Comment: Dear god just looked at that spec. I never considered how complex such a simple sounding task could be

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov: If you're familiar with regex you may remember `\b`, which sounds deceptively simple. Once you realise that it's defined in a way that is totally, and utterly unusable for any human language application, you start searching for a good replacement and then you notice that language is *complex*, like *really complex* ;-) Unicode has the problem that the specifications and algorithms they work out have to work for all languages in use and even those that aren't. I think pretty much all simple-sounding problems with text are that way.

Comment: @fpg1503: Maybe there's an ICU binding for Swift, or Apple has something similar as part of its core APIs. Although I doubt it a bit; such things tend to not be implemented in standard libraries.

Answer (score 0):

For a single character, you cannot decide whether it's a word boundary. You can only decide for two consecutive characters, or rather two consecutive grapheme clusters.

Possibly, this code is useful for you. It creates an array of the word boundaries for a given string. It builds on [NSString.enumerateSubstrings(in:options:using:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1416774-enumeratesubstrings).

You can run it in Playground:

```
import Foundation

let str = "The quick brown_fox jumps over / the lazy dog. Flag   Emoji    ."

extension String {

    public var wordBoundaries: [String.Index] {

        var boundaries: [String.Index] = []

        let start = startIndex
        let end = endIndex
        boundaries.append(start)

        enumerateSubstrings(in: start ..< end, options: .byWords) {
                    substring, substringRange, enclosingRange, stop in

            let lb = substringRange.lowerBound
            if boundaries.last! != lb {
                boundaries.append(substringRange.lowerBound)
            }
            boundaries.append(substringRange.upperBound)
        }
        if boundaries.last! != end {
            boundaries.append(end)
        }

        return boundaries
    }
}


var prevBoundary: String.Index? = nil
for b in str.wordBoundaries {
    if let lower = prevBoundary {
        let s = str[lower ..< b]
        print(s)
    }
    prevBoundary = b
}
```